# new windows position on dual monitor setup ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window-manager, gnome-shell-extension, mutter

is there any shell-extension or something that can force new windows to open on the monitor where the mouse pointer is in a dual monitor setup? even if it is a new instance of an open app like a new window of firefox for example

Comment: compizconfig-settings-manager has an option for that but it only works in unity

Comment: I have a tiny daemon for it. Works no doubt, but couldn't even test it, because I cannot find a single occasion of a window _not_ opening on the screen with mouse (by default, with or without daemon), including firefox (mutter on Ubuntu Budgie). Could you give another example application?

Comment: If you'd like to test the daemon anyway (as said, I am sure it works), just @ ping me.

Comment: Please, any comments on that ^ ?